# Need to shrink data width to fit into table field

Tags: c#, column-width

I have somewhat unusual requirement, we are building an app but recently, it was decided to integrate it with an older system.

The older system requires 6 characters for a vehicle identifier whereas we use 12 in our new system.  The 12 digits are represented as

```
XX    - Year, i.e 19 for 2019
XX    - Store ID, i.e. 12
XXX   - Sales person ID, i.e. 551
XXXXX - VIN sequence #, i.e. 12345
```

So, while older system would need a VIN like 123456, our system provides 191255112345 in a [VehicleNumber] database field.

I thought of breaking up this field into 4 separate fields in database but I am not sure if this is good solution?

I also thought of some sort of mechanism to do the mapping so that I know that 191255112345 refers to 123456 but not sure if there is some pattern or strategy or way to do that already?

How could this be resolved?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Why can't you support old pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there some kind of mapping or convention that your C# app would "know" how to map a 6-digit VIN to a 12-digit Vehicle ID?  If so, use it.

Q: Is there really a need to store the 12-digit Vehicle ID?  Or is the 6 digit VIN sufficient in all cases?  If so, why not just use the VIN?

Otherwise...

Q: Is there a database?  If so, could you provide a mapping table of the 6-digit VIN (presumably "unique") to the 12-digit Vehicle ID?

Comment: Q1: Last 5 digits on NEW system are what 6 digits on old system was, so I'd say this is easy, use string.format("000000") to format to 6 digits this portion  /  Q2: Dont look at VIN as vehicle identification #, it is just some ID.  And yes, there is need for 12 digits on new system  /  Q3: There is no mapping, what used to be 6 digits for sequence is now 5 digits, and we just add on top identifiers for Store, Sales, Year as described.  Not sure if that explains, I understand this question is unusual